Is it possible for multiple people to use a remote desktop at once?
I work at a company where all of our work is done through remote desktops. The biggest drawback, however, is that only 1 person can use the remote desktop at a time. So everyone else can only sit idle and wait for their turn, and this really exacerbates each employee's efficiency and deliveries. Is there any way we can have multiple people accessing the remote desktop, and doing their respective work?

It does not make sense for multiple people to use the same remote desktop as once in the way you described - ie where they have different needs for the same resource - this is because a remote desktop is, more-or-less by definition, a remote interface to the screen, keyboard and mouse of a remote machine - so the short answer to your question is no.
Its outside my area of expertise, but I believe it is possible for some server versions of windows to allow a number of concurrent RDP sessions on Windows using Windows Terminal Server (with an appropriate license) - the difference to what you asked being that each user has a seperate virtual screen and keyboard, and they are not interacting in the same session.   https://woshub.com/how-to-allow-multiple-rdp-sessions-in-windows-10/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/terminal-server-startup-connection-application are worth reading.

Correct, Terminal Services License is required. Non-admin console RDP limit is 2, without a TS license.
